# Dynamically changing certain values of url using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is what my url is: **north.php?slot=0**

What I need to do is change the value of slot when I click on a div which I have it functioning as an arrow. In the div I am using:

`onclick="location.assign('north.php?slot=1')"`.

The div is like this:

`<a onclick="location.assign('north.php?slot=1')"><div class="arrow"></div></a>`.

I am receiving the the value from url as:

```
<?php
    $slot=$_GET['slot'];
?>
```

which is in head tag. Now I want to use this value to access content from my database and display it

I am doing it on xampp server. I have a column named `id` in my table.

```
<?php 
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "tourism portal";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    { 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql="SELECT * FROM north where id=$slot";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {       
        echo $row['name'].'<br>'.'<br>'.$row['description'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: So you have your slot number on the server, great. But you haven't write anything about your database (engine, structure). What have you tried already?

Comment: Hello SQL injection. Also what doesn't work? What is the question?